# не работает saveAs в upload

Tags: yii2, изображения, upload

```
public function upload()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {

        foreach ($this->image as $item) {

            $baseName = $this->image->getBaseName() . "." . $this->image->getExtension();

            $fileName = '@imgPath' . $baseName;

            $item->saveAs(Yii::getAlias($fileName));
            //$this->image->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@imgPath') . $this->image->photo . '.' . $this->image->extension);
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: говорит, что не находит такого метода в этом классе

Comment: Какого метода в каком классе? Где ошибка?

Comment: $item->saveAs(Yii::getAlias($fileName)); -> вот здесь не находит saveAs...

Comment: А что в $item  лежит? Вардамп что говорит?